# Call an async fire and forget SOAP webservice with JMeter

Tags: web-services, soap, jmeter

I'm calling an async fire-and-forget SOAP webservice using jmeter and showing the results in a table.

If i use an WebService(SOAP) Request sampler, it will log the call result as an warning, even if the status code is 200, cause the ws respond with an empty message.

With a SOAP/XML-RPC Request, the log table show te request as concluded.

It's possible to tell to an WebService(SOAP) Request to understand a empty response as a valid response ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I checkd it ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code of WebService Soap sampler it is said that:

> // It is not possible to access the actual HTTP response code, so we assume no data means failure

**Code excerpt:**

```
            // It is not possible to access the actual HTTP response code, so we assume no data means failure
            if (length > 0){
                result.setSuccessful(true);
                result.setResponseCodeOK();
                result.setResponseMessageOK();
            } else {
                result.setSuccessful(false);
                result.setResponseCode("999");
                result.setResponseMessage("Empty response");
            }
```

So you don't have a solution with this sampler.

Another solution is to use HTTP Sampler with Raw Post Body and test only response code with assertion.

I opened a Bugzilla Enhancement request:

- https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53978